# SSISDB Retention Period

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have looked into articles to get the size of SSISDB down.  One good way to do this was set the retention window for logging lower, currently down to 150 from the default of 365 days.

I would like to reduce this to 14 days but would like to be able to keep it at 150 days for packages that log an error.

I think I will have to dig into the SP that runs under the SSIS maint job.  Before I do that I wanted to see if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: If you right click on the SSISDB and choose Reports, Standard Reports, Disk Usage by Top Tables, what do you see listed as the biggest offenders?

Comment: And just to verify, you *are* taking backups, yeah? By default, the SSISDB is going to be in full recovery model so that database will keep growing until the transaction log gets backed up...

Comment: internal  event_message_context
internal  operation_messages
internal  event_messages

Comment: I am using full recovery model and backup nightly.  Also run the SSIS maint job nightly.  We just run a lot of executions and the entries build up fast.